# How to restart kernel and rerun all cells in Python Jupyter notebook through code or by an algorithm?

Tags: python

Need a Python Script that will restart the kernel and rerun all the cells automatically without any human intervention.

I tried the following code below but needs a human intervention since it uses a toggle button.

```
from IPython.display import HTML, Javascript, display

def initialize():
    display(HTML(
        '''
            <script>
                code_show = false;
                function restart_run_all(){
                    IPython.notebook.kernel.restart();
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        IPython.notebook.execute_all_cells();
                    }, 10000)
                }
                function code_toggle() {
                    if (code_show) {
                        $('div.input').hide(200);
                    } else {
                        $('div.input').show(200);
                    }
                    code_show = !code_show
                }
            </script>
            <button onclick="code_toggle()">Click to toggle</button>
            <button onclick="restart_run_all()">Click to Restart and Run all Cells</button>
        '''
    ))
initialize()
```

Comment: Can't you just call `restart_run_all()` inside the `<script>` tag, right after you defined it?

Comment: it's not working

Comment: @ForceBru's suggestion works on my local Jupyter Notebook, but not on Google Colab. Also remember to include a mechanism to stop the "restart_run_all" sequence, or else it'd be an infinite loop...

Answer (score 0):

modifying the code a bit seems to be working for me:

```
from IPython.display import HTML, Javascript, display

def initialize():
    display(HTML(
        '''
            <script>
                code_show = false;
                function restart_run_all(){
                    IPython.notebook.kernel.restart();
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        IPython.notebook.execute_all_cells();
                    }, 10000)
                }
                function code_toggle() {
                    if (code_show) {
                        $('div.input').hide(200);
                    } else {
                        $('div.input').show(200);
                    }
                    code_show = !code_show
                }
                restart_run_all();
            </script>
        '''
    ))
```

Note: I just removed the buttons and called the restart_run_all() function before </ script>